# Where to put Gradle 2.2.1 manually

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on an android app on android studio, my app is trying to fetch a zip from this url http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip but to some unknown reasons it is not able to fetch it, now my question is if I download this zip manually where should I put it to work? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes download the file manually from the gradle Homepage and then it really doesn't matter where you put  the file. Just unzip the file to any directory on you workstation e.g., where you have your programms - and then  in android studio you go File -> Settings -> Build execution Deployment -> Build Tools and there you can define the path to the desired gradle home directory or use the internal graddle wrapper.